# PHP extension: segfault on travis

Tags: php, travis-ci, php-extension

I'm working on a PHP extension that I'm trying to test on travis. Unit tests reveal a segfault that only occur on travis and I can't reproduce it locally no matter what I try.

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff1ccc0000
Core was generated by `/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6/bin/php -d output_handler= -d open_basedir= -'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x000000000095c6b8 in gc_zval_check_possible_root (tsrm_ls=<optimized out>, z=<optimized out>) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend_gc.h:183
183 /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend_gc.h: No such file or directory.

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f759eae4740 (LWP 12532)):
#0 0x000000000095c6b8 in gc_zval_check_possible_root (tsrm_ls=<optimized out>, z=<optimized out>) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend_gc.h:183
#1 i_zval_ptr_dtor (tsrm_ls=<optimized out>, zval_ptr=<optimized out>) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend_execute.h:86
#2 zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=<optimized out>, tsrm_ls=0x32fee10) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:564
#3 0x000000000092194b in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7f759eaa5100, tsrm_ls=0x32fee10) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#4 0x00000000008b1098 in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, tsrm_ls=0x32fee10, retval=0x0, file_count=3) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/Zend/zend.c:1344
#5 0x000000000083e404 in php_execute_script (primary_file=0x7fff1cc7ff70, tsrm_ls=0x32fee10) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/main/main.c:2584
#6 0x0000000000960467 in do_cli (argc=63, argv=0x32fe2f0, tsrm_ls=0x32fee10) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:994
#7 0x000000000044a960 in main (argc=63, argv=0x32fe2f0) at /tmp/php-build/source/5.6.3/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:1378
```

I really don't know what can cause it, since I can't reproduce.

Comment: If you built the extension, you should debug it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well with Python, and [I'm not alone](https://travis-ci.org/imageio/imageio/jobs/38979664). So it may be tagged with python as well. since i assume it's the same issue.